# Loading logo on Customer Portal login page

Tags: customer-portal, custom

I have noticed that the logo I have placed in my login page template for Customer Portal does not load unless the user is already logged into Salesforce, which defeats the purpose of it as customers will not have access to this.

The logo itself is actually a static resource but has been set to public in the share settings.

Could anyone shed some light on this behavior and how I could fix it? Possibly *without* hosting the image outside Salesforce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static resources are only accessible once a user has been authenticated. But you can setup your logo as a document that can be marked as an "Externally Available Image".

The URL to access that logo is then:

```
https://{SALESFORCE-INSTANCE}.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?oid={ORG-ID}&id={DOC-ID}
```

See [How do I reference a public image stored in salesforce.com in my HTML?](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005050&language=en_US) for the details.

For a Site you would replace `{SALESFORCE-INSTANCE}.salesforce.com` with the Site default web address e.g. `mydomain.secure.force.com/mysite`.